# Is there any way to encapsulate UIAlertController within another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, backwards-compatibility, uialertcontroller, forward-compatibility

I'm fairly new to iOS, so please keep answers clear.  I've been toying with encapsulating UIAlertController in another UIViewController to use it as a replacement for UIActionSheet as it's deprecated in iOS 8.

The idea would be a replacement for UIActionSheet that is backward and forward compatible, , call it ImmortalActionSheet for instance.

If the component is used in iOS 8  or greater, it can use UIAlertController, otherwise it would fall back to UIActionSheet.  That would make it a backward and forward compatible action sheet to replace many action sheets around an application I'm working with.  And yes I need to maintain backward compatibility.

I've prototyped this but for whatever reason, when I present ImmortalActionSheet, the UIAlertController view itself will always show up at the top left (0, 0).  No matter if I change the center, it never moves.

```
-(void) loadView
{
     UIView * child = nil;
     if ( [UIAlertController class] )
     {
         UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Make Choice!!" message:@"Choose one!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
         for (UIAlertAction * action in actions ){
             [alertController addAction:action];
         }

         child = alertController.view;
         [self addChildViewController:alertController];
     }

     self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [self.view addSubview:child];
}
```

[image: UIAlertController moved to a buggy position]

Comment: There is already a similar backwards-compatible wrapper which might interest you: https://github.com/steipete/PSTAlertController

Comment: >  the UIAlertController view itself will always show up at the top left (0, 0). - Do you have an image of this?

Comment: Certainly, @pkamb.  Edited the question to show the screenshot.  I'm essentially having the UIAlertController create the view, and then adding the view from it as a subview of my UIController.

Comment: I just added a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028983/uialertcontroller-is-moved-to-buggy-position-at-top-of-screen-when-it-calls-pre

Comment: I created a ShowSystemAlert class that handles old and new versions of the alert. I documented it here. http://www.wellgolly.com/?p=2010