# UIAlertController has a wrong position after dismiss another UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I made a custom `UIAlertController` in the upper part of it is I `UICollectionView` with photos. I present `TOCropViewController` (this is `UIViewController`) of a custom from my `UIAlertController`, and when I'm `TOCropViewController`, the `UIAlertController` be in the wrong position. Also, I did a little experiment to find out exactly what the problem is not `TOCropViewController`, and presented a default `UIViewController`, but the result is the same. Please tell me how to fix it?

So I present any controller from `UIAlertController`

```
private func presentCropViewController(_ image: UIImage) {
    let cropViewController = TOCropViewController(croppingStyle: .circular, image: image)

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

this give the same result

```
  let testVC = UIViewController()
        testVC.view.backgroundColor = .red

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.present(testVC, animated: true, completion: {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                    testVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            })
        }
```

When the controller which was presented the result of such a hiding.

[image]

Comment: I found much more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028983/uialertcontroller-is-moved-to-buggy-position-at-top-of-screen-when-it-calls-pre) I will use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37713178/4981515)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController is moved to buggy position at top of screen when it calls \`presentViewController:\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028983/uialertcontroller-is-moved-to-buggy-position-at-top-of-screen-when-it-calls-pre)