# React Native Alert showing off screen

Tags: react-native

Im calling Alert on `componentDidMount` in a function

```
Alert.alert(
      'Location Access Disclosure',
      'This app collects location data to enable tracking in the background',
      [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          onPress: () => {
            dispatch(setupGeolocationService());
          }
        }
      ]
    );
```

Not sure why the Alert is sometimes showing up off screen like this.
[image: Alert off screen]

Comment: you are not using any position : absolute on your parent View or something ?

Comment: @CyrusZei no and if you kill the app and come back to it, it displays correctly.

Comment: Switched to using a modal. Issue may be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028983/uialertcontroller-is-moved-to-buggy-position-at-top-of-screen-when-it-calls-pre